# scrapy response.xpath only picking out the first item

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the html structure

```
  <div class="column first">
    <div class="detail">
      <strong>Phone: </strong>
      <span class="value"> 012-345-6789</span>
    </div>
    <div class="detail">
      <span class="value">1 Street Address, Big Road, City, Country</span>
    </div>
    <div class="detail">
      <h3 class="inline">Area:</h3>
      <span class="value">Georgetown</span>
    </div>
    <div class="detail">
      <h3 class="inline">Nearest Train:</h3>
      <span class="value">Georgetown Station</span>
    </div>
    <div class="detail">
      <h3 class="inline">Website:</h3>
      <span class="value"><a href='http://www.website.com' target='_blank'>www.website.com</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When I run `sel = response.xpath('//span[@class="value"]/text()')` in scrapy shell I get what I expect back, which is:

```
[<Selector xpath='//span[@class="value"]/text()' data=u' 012-345-6789'>, <Selector xpath='//span[@class="value"]/text()' data=u'1 Street Address, Big Road, City, Country'>, <Selector xpath='//span[@class="value"]/text()' data=u'Georgetown Station'>, <Selector xpath='//span[@class="value"]/text()' data=u' '>, <Selector xpath='//span[@class="value"]/text()' data=u'January, 2016'>]
```

However, in the parse block in my scrapy spider, it's only returning the first item

```
def parse(self, response):
    def extract_with_xpath(query):
        return response.xpath(query).extract_first().strip()

    yield {
        'details': extract_with_xpath('//span[@class="value"]/text()')
    }
```

I realise I am using `extract_first()` but if I use `extract()` it breaks, even though I know `extract()` is a legitimate function.

What I am doing wrong? Do I need to loop through the 
`extract_with_xpath('//span[@class="value"]/text()')` part?

Thanks for any enlightenment!

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something. I don't see any `div` tag with an attribute of a class named "title". What are you trying to extract from your HTML document?

Comment: The 'title' part extraction is fine. I have removed it from the code to avoid further confusion. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Drew Davis I am trying to extract all the text from the `<span class="value">` elements. But at the moment my scrape only pulls the first one.

Comment: Got it. Before I submit my answer, is your code hosted anywhere online? Would you mind pasting the URL in your "start_urls" list? I just need to verify it works before I send my solution.

Comment: _"but if I use extract() it breaks"_ what do you mean by that? What is the expected output of your parse method from the sample you provided?

Comment: I expect it to extract all the items with that tag and not just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

in items.py, specify-

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class yourProjectNameItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    name = Field()
    details= Field()
```

in your scrapy spider:
imports:

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from yourProjectName.items import yourProjectNameItem
import re
```

and the parse function as follows:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    i = yourProjectNameItem()

    i['name'] = hxs.select('YourXPathHere').extract() 
    i['details'] = hxs.select('YourXPathHere').extract()

    return i
```

Hope this solves the issue.
You can refer to my project on git:https://github.com/omkar-dsd/SRMSE/tree/master/Scrapers/NasaScraper

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This would be a complete rewrite of my code. What I have so far is working for the most part, my only problem is iterating over some tags in one of the responses.